# do-while doesn't quit on first 'q'

Tags: d, do-while

So I'm working on a simple little text-based game in D to gain some experience working with the language. Here is a do-while loop that I'm currently struggling with:

```
do{
  writeln("a. Advance 1 year\tc. Advance 10 years\tq. Quit");
  writeln("b. Advance 5 years\td. Modify faction");

  input = chomp(stdin.readln());

  switch(input){
    ...
    default:
      break;
  }
  writeln(input[0]);
}while(input[0] != 'q');
```

Now the problem I'm running into is that when I hit q and enter the loop doesn't exit. It just keeps going. But then after the first time q is input, another q will terminate the loop. The writeln is in there as a sanity check, and it prints out the characters I type in exactly as typed. I feel like I'm going crazy, but it's probably just a simple type-o or something you guys will spot instantly. Nothing in the switch statement modifies 'input'.

EDIT: Okay some people have been asking to see all of the code. Here it is: http://pastebin.com/A7qM5nGW

When I said nothing in the switch modified input, it was to hide the fact I hadn't written anything in the switch yet. I've been trying to get the quit part to work right before adding the more complicated stuff. Also, here's a sample file for what I run it on: http://pastebin.com/4c2f4Z5N

Comment: can you post the whole program at all? this looks right eyeballing it but there might be a buffering issue elsewhere or something.

Comment: sticking this in a main loop behaves as expected. I would try just running this without the surrounding code to prove to yourself it works, then start adding back the other pieces until it breaks again. Or just post the whole program so we can take a better look.

Comment: "Nothing in the switch statement modifies 'input'" may still be untrue if some buffer overflow clobbers your variables. We can't tell.

Comment: I also took the code, compiled it and it works like expected, so you most probably have the problem elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Okay I pasted all the code I have so far to a pastebin. Along with the file that I've been using to test it. Can file I/O interfere with strings from a different section of main? I'm pretty new to D, so I'm not sure what buffer you guys are talking about, unless you mean the input buffer, but that shouldn't affect a input though should it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay my friend found it. It has nothing to do with the while loop itself. I briefly forgot that args[0] is the name of the program. So it's actually running through the parent loop once with nothing, then actually quitting, and then running through the appropriate loop. It was fixed by making the parent loop like so...

```
foreach(filename; args[1..$]){
    ...
    do{
        ...
    while(input[0] != 'q');
}
```

as opposed to:

```
foreach(filename; args){
```

etc...